# User input on command prompt

Tags: vb.net, command-line, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

I need to automate usage of a command line utility in VB.net. here is an example.

From the code, I need to decrypt a file using command line utility. Here is the command line procedure.

You start utility using this line

`C:\gnupg>gpg --decrypt c:\temp\File_Encr.xml`

Once executed, then it shows this

`You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
user: "xxxx <abc@def.com>"
1024-bit ELG-E key, ID ABCD, created 2013-10-25 (main key ID DEF)`

Enter passphrase:

and when you enter the passphrase, it do the job.
I need start this process from the code (VB.NET) and input passphrase as well so that it doesn't require any user interaction. My code will be used in Windows Services as well as Web application.

Can someone help on this please?

Thank you.
   Sameers

Comment: The given program has to allow you to introduce the "user inputs" as arguments; you have to follow the rules/syntax of the given problem. Relevant page for the program you are referring: http://www.spywarewarrior.com/uiuc/gpg/gpg-com-4.htm

Comment: I understand that, if that was the case, I didn't needed to spent this much time on this thing. Problem is, program doesn't seems be supporting the passphrase via command line when we call it. It does ask only when the main command line is executed.

Comment: As explained, if the target program does not allow you to interact with it via command prompt, you cannot do it. In the most likely scenario, it allows you but you don't have clear the exact syntax. The only way to fix this problem (if possible at all) is looking at the instructions provided by the target software manufacturer; there is nothing you can do from your end (via Process class) other than a (blind) trial-and-error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code snippet I use.

All output code is written to the Visual Studio debug window for convenience. All program output all redirected to output handlers. This allows you to inspect the output coming out of the program in "real time". If you needed to watch the output lines and scan for a certain phrase and then perform an action, you could easily do this in Sub OutputReceivedHandler().

I tried to make it generic so you can see how it works:

```
    Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
    Imports System.Diagnostics
    Imports System

    Public Class ExternalUtilities

        Private myprocess As Process
        Private SW As System.IO.StreamWriter
        Private myprocess_HasError As Boolean = False
        Private myprocess_ErrorMsg As String = ""
        Private myprocess_Output As String = ""

        Public Sub New()
            ' do init stuff here.
            ' maybe pass the executable path, or command line args.
        End Sub

        Public Sub launchUtilityProcess1()

            Dim executeableFullPath As String = "C:\Path\To\file.exe"

            ' define the process
            myprocess = New Process
            myprocess.StartInfo.FileName = executeableFullPath
            myprocess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
            myprocess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
            myprocess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
            myprocess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
            myprocess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
            myprocess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(executeableFullPath)
            myprocess.StartInfo.Arguments = "--decrypt c:\temp\File_Encr.xml"

            ' add handlers to monitor various conditions
            myprocess.EnableRaisingEvents = True
            AddHandler myprocess.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf OutputReceivedHandler
            AddHandler myprocess.ErrorDataReceived, AddressOf ErrorReceivedHandler
            AddHandler myprocess.Exited, AddressOf ExitedHandler

            ' launch
            Try
                myprocess.Start()

                ' redirect this processes IO
                SW = myprocess.StandardInput
                SW.AutoFlush = True

                ' use asynchronous reading so buffers dont fill up
                myprocess.BeginOutputReadLine()
                myprocess.BeginErrorReadLine()

                ' wait for program to end
                myprocess.WaitForExit()
                myprocess.Close()
                SW.Close()
                myprocess.Dispose()

                ' check for errors
                If myprocess_ErrorMsg  "" Then
                    ' something bad happened, handle it.
                End If

            Catch ex As Exception
                ' something bad happened, handle it.
            End Try


        End Sub

        Private Sub OutputReceivedHandler(ByVal sendingProcess As Object, ByVal line As DataReceivedEventArgs)

            If Not line.Data Is Nothing Then

                If line.Data = "string to search for..." Then
                    ' when this string is detected, send more output
                    SW.Write("helloworld" & System.Environment.NewLine)
                ElseIf line.Data = "something else..." Then
                    ' when this string is detected, send more output
                    SW.Write("goodbyeworld" & System.Environment.NewLine)
                End If

                Debug.WriteLine(line.Data)
            End If

        End Sub

        Private Sub ErrorReceivedHandler(ByVal sendingProcess As Object, ByVal line As DataReceivedEventArgs)

            Debug.WriteLine(line.Data)

            '   These executables send newlines on the STDERR path, ignore newlines
            If line.Data <> "" Then
                myprocess_HasError = True
                myprocess_ErrorMsg = line.Data
            End If

        End Sub

        Private Sub ExitedHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
            Debug.WriteLine("Process Exited")
        End Sub

    End Class
```

Comment: I tried this and the execution never goes beyond myprocess.WaitForExit() statement. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Check your debug window in visual studio, the program is likely waiting for more user input. You can examine lines in Sub OutputReceivedHandler() and make decisions based of the lines that are printed. You can move "myprocess" into a wider scope if needed so the subroutines can access it and send further commands.

Comment: I already tried it, there is nothing there. even added break points to OutputReceivedHandler and ErrorReceivedHandler and ExitedHandler and it never reaches there. (Jut stucked on myprocess.WaitForExit(). If I manually enter the passpharse on command pompt (I tried making that visible) then it continues further. Otherwise, it just stucks there.

Comment: I use this exact code to run various command line executables. It will need some customizations of course. I'm not certain how you program works. For example, if you need to pass arguments directly when the process is executed try:

myprocess.StartInfo.Arguments = "--decrypt c:\temp\File_Encr.xml"

Comment: David, I really appreciate your help here. Its a lot for me. Yes, I already have tried by providing Arguments (without that it was not even starting the process properly). What I expect is that when we use SW.Write ("password" & vbCRLF or Envoirnment.NewLine) or SW.WriteLine("Password") application should goto next line (after accepting password). However, it is still stucked on that line and doesn't continue. I will try more tweaks to see if that works.

Comment: Edited. I moved the "SW" & "myprocess" object into a wider scope and tested this. I do this stuff all the time & it definitely works for me using this exact code, sorry I can't help you :]